# how to convert xml (dublin core) to csv in python?

Tags: python, xml, metadata

I have a bunch of biodiversity metadata in the following format. I want to cluster them using machine learning algorithms and I thought maybe it could be a good idea if I convert the data first from XML to CSV. Could it be a good idea? if yes? is there an easy way to convert it in Python to CSV or any other more machine-readable format?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="urn:pangaea.de:dataportals" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:pangaea.de:dataportals http://ws.pangaea.de/schemas/pansimple/pansimple.xsd">
  <dc:title>Sorex araneus Linnaeus, 1758, a preserved specimen record of the Mammals (recent) dataset [ID: ZMB_Mam_050329 ]</dc:title>
  <dc:description>The Animal Sound Archive at the Museum fuer Naturkunde Berlin (German: Tierstimmenarchiv) is one of the oldest and largest worldwide. Founded in 1951 by Professor Guenter Tembrock the collection consists now of around 130 000 records of animal voices.</dc:description>
  <dc:contributor>Christiane Funk</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>MfN</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Museum für Naturkunde Berlin – Leibniz Institute for Research on Evolution and Biodiversity, Berlin</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Zenker, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Zenker, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:contributor>Kulicke, R</dc:contributor>
  <dc:publisher>Data Center MfN</dc:publisher>
  <dataCenter>Data Center MfN</dataCenter>
  <dc:type>ABCD_Unit</dc:type>
  <dc:type>preserved specimen</dc:type>
  <dc:format>text/html</dc:format>
  <dc:identifier>ZMB_Mam_050329</dc:identifier>
  <dc:source>MfN Custodians (2017). MfN Zoological Collections - Mammals (recent). [Dataset]. Data Publisher: Museum für Naturkunde Berlin (MfN) - Leibniz Institute for Research on Evolution and Biodiversity.</dc:source>
  <linkage type="metadata">http://biocase.naturkundemuseum-berlin.de/current?dsa=mfn_Mammalia&amp;detail=unit&amp;schema=http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/abcd/2.06&amp;cat=ZMB_Mam_050329</linkage>
  <dc:coverage xsi:type="CoverageType">
    <northBoundLatitude>52.4256800000</northBoundLatitude>
    <westBoundLongitude>14.2540400000</westBoundLongitude>
    <southBoundLatitude>52.4256800000</southBoundLatitude>
    <eastBoundLongitude>14.2540400000</eastBoundLongitude>
    <startDate>1961-08-03T00:00:00</startDate>
    <endDate>1961-08-03T00:00:00</endDate>
  </dc:coverage>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Mammalia</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Soricidae</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Sorex</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="kingdom" xsi:type="SubjectType">Animalia</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Soricomorpha</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Chordata</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="taxonomy" xsi:type="SubjectType">Sorex araneus Linnaeus, 1758</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="parameter" xsi:type="SubjectType">Date</dc:subject>
  <dc:subject type="parameter" xsi:type="SubjectType">Locality</dc:subject>
  <dc:rights>CC-BY-SA</dc:rights>
  <dc:relation>http://coll.mfn-berlin.de/c/ZMB_MAM</dc:relation>
  <parentIdentifier>urn:gfbio.org:abcd:1_66_118</parentIdentifier>
  <additionalContent>MfN, ZMB_Mam, ZMB_Mam_050329, 2013-10-29T17:22:54, Mammalia, class, Soricidae, family, Sorex, genusgroup, Animalia, kingdom, Soricomorpha, order, Chordata, phylum, Sorex araneus Linnaeus, 1758, Sorex, araneus, Linnaeus, 1758, Preserved specimen, Skull, 1961-08-03T00:00:00, Kulicke, Kulicke, Schwenow, Germany, country, Germany, DE, state, Brandenburg, Schwenow, Male </additionalContent>
</dataset>
```

Please let me know if you have some suggestions

Comment: What did you try? Thank you for posting the XML but where is your attempted Python code? Recall: `data` + `code` = [mcve].

Comment: # parsing the XML files
tree = et.parse('./output/3367.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for i in root:
    title = i.tag.find("title")
    print(title)
it tried this but I couldn't get the title

Comment: Please post code in body of post and not in hard to read comments. Also, your XML has namespaces which you must acknowledge or no content will be parsed. Search StackOverflow in Google/Bing for this often asked issue.

Comment: the problem was the namespaces thank you very much